# Modify an existing link in org-mode with mini-buffer prompts

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to modify an existing link in org-mode with mini-buffer prompts?

Modifying the link syntax as it was written seems to be really fiddly and unpredictable because of emac’s URL hiding behavior. I’ve taken to binding `org-toggle-link-display` to `C-c L` but what I’d really like to just be able to put my cursor over any part of the link and then prompted in the mini-buffer like this:

```
URL: http://example.com
```

and then

```
Link text: foobar
```

for a link like this:

```
[[http://example.com][foobar]]
```

and be able to change either of those however I wish.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `org-insert-link` which is bounded to `C-c C-l`. When the point is on a link, this will open what you want in the mini-buffer. An advantage: you can edit long links/descriptions that can span over lines!

Comment: Damn, I had no idea that command was able to modify existing links as well. Thanks @Dror